# «Вопрос задан не на русском языке» как стандартная причина тревоги

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, тревоги

Часто новички задают на ruSO вопросы не на русском языке. Попробую подтвердить «часто» количеством полезных тревог по данной причине только с двух свежих страниц [моих тревог](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/199934?group=0&status=0&page=1).

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]

6 случаев, каждый раз я тревожил, поставив галочку напротив «Требуется внимание модератора», вписывая причину вручную. Как мне кажется, если эту причину тревоги нередко указывают и остальные участники, есть основание сделать её стандартной. То есть, чтобы можно было тревожить быстрее, к примеру, <kbd>Тревога</kbd> → <kbd>Вопрос не на русском языке</kbd> → <kbd>Отметить вопрос тревогой</kbd>.

Comment: 5 - сомнение...

Comment: @Ancient, видимо, первоначально вопрос задали не на русском, но потом были произведены изменения.

Comment: Чёрных, видимо, человек из 5 вопроса английский знает лучше, чем русский, потому задавал на английском :D

Comment: Как в таких случаях не хватает шаблонов с ХэшКода... http://i.stack.imgur.com/I5bkG.png

Comment: Отличное предложение! Пожалуйста, опубликуйте в ответе к этому вопросу пример(ы) описания причины закрытия.

Answer (score 1):

> каждый раз я тревожил, поставив галочку напротив «Требуется внимание
>   модератора», вписывая причину вручную. Как мне кажется, если эту
>   причину тревоги нередко указывают и остальные участники, есть
>   основание сделать её стандартной.

Не думаю, что таких вопросов встречается достаточно много среди общего числа вопросов, на которые следует обратить внимание модераторам, чтобы для них специально выделять поле для обоснования тревоги.

Вписать строку "Вопрос не на русском" в описании к тревоги не такая уж и большая задача, тем более, как указал выше, это требуется не так уж и часто для пользователей сайта.

Comment: > Не думаю, что таких вопросов встречается достаточно много среди общего числа — Не могли бы обосновать какими-то статистическими данными фразу «не думаю»? Я привёл статистику для собственных тревог, если у других тревоги данного типа имеют такой же процент среди общего числа тревог, то предложение, возможно, имеет право на существование. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных На моей памяти, вопроса два-три попадалось мне за всё время нахождения на данном сайте. Возможно я не на те метки подписан, где это происходит весьма часто.

Comment: мне они попадаются в [**очереди проверок**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review), у этих вопросов самые разные метки. Вероятно, следовало уточнить в вопросе-предложении, что под «остальными участниками» имеются в виду проверяющие сообщения новичков.

Comment: "Вопрос не на русском" — это плохое объяснение. Хорошее объяснение должно включать рекомендацию задать вопрос на подходящем сайте или перевести на русский язык.

Comment: @Discord а какая разница? Всё равно из "Вопрос не на русском" следует эти решения "Перенос на другой сайт", либо "Перевод на русский", а может и вовсе удаление вопроса, мало ли что там написано.
P.S. Проверяющий может не знать "не русский" на достаточном уровне, чтобы выбрать более конкретное объяснение.